# When are cubic solutions "simple"

Tags: radicals, cubics

Is there any way to tell from the coefficients of a cubic equation (with integer coefficients) whether or not the solutions will all have a "simple" form. By "simple" I mean of the form

$a + b\sqrt{c}$

where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$

So, for example, the following would all be "simple" solutions:

$\bullet$ $2 + 3\sqrt{3}$

$\bullet$ $6$

$\bullet$ $\sqrt{5}$

$\bullet$ $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2\sqrt{7}}{2}$

An example of a non-simple solution would be the solutions to $8x^3-5x^2+4x-4$ (try typing into wolfram alpha and see the resulting monstrosity)

Comment: this can only happen when the cubic possesses a rational root, which is the same as being divisible by some linear $mx + n$ (when all the coefficients are integers)

Comment: what about the roots to the cubic that factorizes as $(x+\sqrt{2})(2x+\sqrt{3})(3x+\sqrt{5})$? This has no rational root but all the roots are "simple"

Comment: Yes, but the coefficients are not all integers or all rational.

Comment: Ooohh, duh. Would you mind giving some kind of proof of your assertion? I intuitively believe it, but I'll accept a proof as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the cubic is irreducible and the coefficients are integers it cannot have a root of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}\ $ because the minimal polynomial of such a number over $\mathbb Q$ has at most degree $2$.

Comment: would you mind explaining this just a little more? I know what a minimal polynomial is, but I'm having trouble seeing exactly what you mean

Comment: A number of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$ has minimal polynomial at most $2$. You can isolate $\sqrt{c}$ and square.

Comment: But the minimal polynomial of a root of an irreducible cubic over $\mathbb Q$ is the cubic itself because a smaller polynomial with such a root would divide the cubic, but we assumed it is irreducible.

Comment: OK, so for an arbitrary cube with integer coefficients, it will have a "simple" solution if and only if it is reducible? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly.